# counting number of non-constant function from set A to B

Tags: real-analysis

As we know number of functions from set A to set B is |B|^|A|, where |A| represents number of elements in set A etc. 
so is there is any formula to calculate number of non-constant functions from set A to B. please provide me examples too.

Comment: You know how many functions there are from $A$ to $B$. Do you know how many constant functions there are?

Comment: Seems obvious to me. If you know the number of functions, and the number of constants, isn't the answer just the difference? This assumes all is finite.

Answer (score 3):

This is the same as the total number of functiosn minus the number of constant functions. So we ask, how many constant functions are there?

How many values can a function from $A$ to $B$ take? It can take $|B|$ values, and so there are $|B|$ constant functions from $A$ to $B$ as long as $|A| \neq 0$.

Comment: so, if A and B are non-empty sets then, number of non-constant functions are
 |B|^|A| – |B|